# How do I log in Program.Main in .net core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Previously I could use `LoggerFactory` but now it is marked as obsolete.
How can I access `ILoggingBuilder` and create logger instance at the beginning of `Main`method? I want to use builtin logger not any 3rd party logging library.

Comment: What do you want to log?

Comment: `I want to use builtin logger not any 3rd party logging library.`- You cannot because ASP.NET Core default logger does not support file logging or database logging yet!

Comment: @Joshit for example reason why app failed. Catch exceptions coming from host.Run() and log it.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I want to log to console.

Comment: Okay! then surely you can! Wait.

Comment: @PiotrPerak sorry for being late.. Had some private issues yesterday ;) hope my answer gives you the information needed

Comment: @PiotrPerak can you please give me some feedback regarding my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, you have to edit CreateWebHostBuilder method:

```
public static IWebHost CreateWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole(); // Or any other provider
        }).Build();
```

Now this method returns the host with configured logging. Now you can get you ILogger-Service from the services of your host:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHost(args);
    try
    {
        var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Called from Main");
        host.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // do something
    } 
}
```

To use Logging in Startup you can still use ILoggerFactory:

```
private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
}
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    try
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup");
        // log 
        throw;
    }
}
```

Here are additional ressources for [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [app startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in asp.net core 2.2.

Comment: Problem with this is you will not log if Build() fails. With LoggerFactory you were able to create logger as first thing in Main().

Comment: In Startup class for example. And if I wanted to log "App is starting" before building the host?

Comment: you can still use ILoggerFactory. Only .AddConsole()-Extension (and others) is deprecated. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/238

Comment: As another resource check this blogpost from Scott Allen: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/07/16/7-tips-for-troubleshooting-asp-net-core-startup-errors.aspx

Comment: AddConsole is exactly what I wanted to use and that's why I asked this question. It's obsolete now.

Comment: But you can use AddConsole() - just in a slightly different way.. I´ve edited my question again - anyway.. Sorry if I don´t get you right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187239/discussion-between-joshit-and-piotr-perak).

Comment: Passing ILoggerFactory loggerFactory as a constructor parameter is not possible in .net core 3.0 anymore.

Comment: What if an exception happens in this line:  `var host = CreateWebHost(args);`